# Fixed header and ordered list filter issue

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Im using JQM and phonegap to create a simple app. In Android everything's fine, but when I run the app in an IOS device the keyboard makes some strange effect on the screen

If the list is not scrolled, everything seems to be working, 
[image: no-scroll, showing header]

but if I scroll the list a little bit and make the keyboard appear, the hell breaks loose:

[image: scrolled list, not showing header]

HTML

```
<div id="my-wrapper">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a"  data-filter="true" data-filter-theme='b' data-filter-placeholder="Buscar Producto y/o Droga"  id="RemediosList">
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#my-wrapper {
    top : 45px;
}
#my-wrapper form {
    position :fixed;
    top      : 87px;
    left     : 15px;
    width    : 100%;
    z-index  : 10000;
}
```

Any help, will be welcomed!

Comment: try inserting some `<li>` elements. had the same problem with empty `<ul>` elemnts in jqm

Comment: the <li> elements are already inserted dynamically. As you can see in the screen captures

Comment: you have the listview inside header?

Comment: No, I don't, first we have the header, then the content and afterwards the Listview.

Comment: i guess the problem is caused by `position: fixed` because fixed header has `position: fixed`.

Comment: Ok... and what can I do about it?

Comment: Did You solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to remove the header and only have a fixed seachbox. Works perfect on desktop and Android. But I get the same result in iOS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<title>title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#wrp {
padding-top : 45px;
}
#wrp form {
position :fixed!important;
top      : 13px;
left     : 15px;
width    : 100%;
z-index  : 2;

}
</style>

</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-dom-cache="true">

<div data-role="content">

<div id="wrp">

<ul id="search" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Sök.." data-inset="false" data-filter-theme="a">

    <li><h2>header<h2></li>
</ul>

</div><!-- /my wrapper -->


</div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```